# Which site do I ask questions regarding installing Linux?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I wish to install Linux on my machine and have questions where can I ask them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Ubuntu flavoured distributions I would try [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour).

And maybe [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) for other distributions.

If you want to see what all the sites are you should give the Stack Exchange [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page a look.

Answer (score 4):

You can ask on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com.

**Super User FAQ**

What kind of questions can I ask here?

- Computer hardware
- Computer software
- Personal and home computer networking

**Unix FAQ**

What kind of questions can I ask here?

- Using or administering a *nix desktop or server
- The Unix foundation underlying Mac OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)
- The underlying *nix OS on an embedded system or handheld device (e.g. an Android phone)
  Shell scripting
- Applications packaged in *nix distributions (note: being cross-platform does not disqualify)
  UNIX C API and System Interfaces